# Como uno registros si fechas de inicio y termino son consecutivas?

Tags: python, date, dataframe

he tratado de generar una función sin frutos. De necesidad urgente tengo un Dataframe estructurado y ordenado con registros de contratos. Necito unir registros siempre que todos los campos, salvo en las fechas de inicio y termino, sean idénticos. Y, además, que la fecha de termino del registro i este separada de la fecha de inicio del registro i+1 por un día. Los registros que no puedan unirse deben quedar sin modificar. Dejo ejemplo en imágenes, Dataframe real es más extenso en columnas y registros

[image: imagen referencial de dataframe original y resultado esperado]